# Replace text in on a title [angularjs controller]

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd like to replace text that will be showed on the menu and at the same time I got data from the database.

E.G.:

```
$rootScope.MyMenu = [{
        id: "1",
        title: "Arte e Spettacoli"
}, {
        id: "2",
        title: "Sanitá"
}
```

I had to collapse both strings like "arteespettacoli" and "sanita" but what I want to read are "Arte e Spettacoli" and "Sanitá".

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: I don't get it. You want to show on your menu "Arte e Spettacoli" and "Sanitá", but you have to collapse both strings like "arteespettacoli" and "sanita". Please clarify this.

Comment: To get contents from the database I need to set both without spaces and special characters.

Comment: Anyone that could help me solving this issue?

Comment: If I use this title: "arteespettacoli".replace("arteespettacoli","Arte e Spettacoli") it can't get anymore the feed. If I use this title: "arteespettacoli" without replace it will correctly get the feed but I will show the menu as "arteespettacoli"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have both values, one for displaying it on the title and the other one for getting the feed, you could create an additional key for getting the feed and leave the first one for displaying it. Something like this:

```
$rootScope.MyMenu = [{
        id: "1",
        title: "Arte e Spettacoli",
        key: "arteespettacoli"
}, {
        id: "2",
        title: "Sanitá",
        key: "sanita"
}
```

Now you can show your title by accessing to `$rootScope.MyMenu[index].title` (get `index` in `$rootScope.MyMenu` array somehow) and make the request with `$rootScope.MyMenu[index].key`

The way you create this additional key depends on how you're handling this data. You can use replace as you commented before.